# tinyMCE Jquery and PHP form submittion

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

Am trying to submit stuff typed in tinyMCE using a Jquery function but am not certain how to do that and how the server side form-processor should accept the data.

This is what I have so far.
Anyone see something that am missing here? I know am close. am just missing something.

Thanks in advance.

==THE HTML==

```
<form  onsubmit="save_tinyMCE_Stuff();" method="post" action="form_processor.php?action=save" >
  <textarea  class="classname" id="tme0" name="elm1" rows="25" cols="80" style="width: 100%" >Product Details Will appear Here. This information will be compiled by purchasing Department<br/>
  Some Text here
  </textarea><br /><input type="submit" name="save" value="Save" /><input type="reset" name="reset" value="Undo All" />
</form>
```

==THE SCRIPT IN HTML FILE==

```
save_tinyMCE_Stuff(){
  $dataString = tinymce.get('tme0').getContent();
  $zeurl = 'form_processor.php?action=save&data=' + $dataString;
  $.ajax({type: "POST",url: $zeurl,data: $dataString,cache: false,success: function(result){alert(result);}});
}
```

==THE PHP==

```
  form_processor.php
  <?php
if($_GET['action'] == 'save'){
  echo $_POST['WHAT NAME TO USE HERE'];
}
  ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to tinymce. Just submit textarea value.

like this:

```
function save_tinyMCE_Stuff() {

    $dataString = $('textarea').val();
    $zeurl = 'form_processor.php?action=save&data=' + $dataString;
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: $zeurl,
        data: $dataString,
        cache: false,
        success: function(result) {
            alert(result);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: @James yes, and you have to use class or id for jquery selector instead textarea :)

Answer (score 0):

If a form gets submitted, it will become available as the `name` attribute the element has. So for your tinyMCE stuff, it would be `$_POST['elm1'];`

Because the `name` of your textarea is elm1.

Getting all textarea's with jquery example: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nqoqfwa0/1/)

Comment: Thanks!  Although I must note that I have multiple textareas in the page. and with that in mind. I thought I could do this :   $SinblingtextArea = $(this).siblings('textarea:first');  which gives me the teat area that is a sibling of the clicked button. my question is, can I submit  "$SinblingtextArea" as the textarea using ajax? I have tried doing $testmsg = $SinblingtextArea.attr("class"); alert($testmsg); and it come up as undefined. is there something am doing wrong again here?

Comment: @James, what you can do is the following: use jquery and ajax to save all the textareas. Use Jquery `$.each()` function to loop through all the textareas. Give all textareas a class of textarea or something, and in the `$.each()` function make a call with ajax.

Comment: Ok. I figured it out. I gave all the forms including tinyMCE's different  classes and id and did this in the script to pick which one was clicked .       $dataString = thisObject.closest('form').find('textarea');
           $.ajax({
                  type: "POST",
                  url: $zeurl,
                  data: $dataString,
                  cache: false,
                  success: function(result) {
                          alert(result);
                  }
           });
Thanks alot everyone!!